# Calls one column of a dataframe, turns it into an array and plots it

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pandas, data-visualization

My code calls 1 column of a dataframe, turns it into an array and plots it.
I want to able to do this for all the columns without having to repeat the code many times.

How can I do this?

```
#Code to create fake data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,5), columns=list('abcde'),
     index=list('nopqrstuvw'))
df.columns.name = 'level_0'
df.index.name = 'level_1'



#I load an array of shape (10, 2)
sensors_pos = sio.loadmat('/home/Coord_Slp_2D.mat')['Cor']


# I extract column "a"
df1=df['Total Acc'].round(4)*100
df2=df1.reset_index().pivot('level_1', 'level_0', 'Total Acc')

df3=df2['a'].reset_index() #extracts the column "a"


#Turns column "a" into an array
data=df3['a'].values   


#Plots column "a"
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (8,5))
ax,_ = plot_topomap(data, sensors_pos, cmap='viridis', show=False) 
plt.title('a')
fig.colorbar(ax)
fig.show()


#------------------------------
#This is where the repetition starts. I will have to do this for each column

 # I extract column "b"

df4=df2['b'].reset_index() #extracts the column "b"


#Turns column "b" into an array
data=df3['b'].values   


#Plots column "b"
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (8,5))
ax,_ = plot_topomap(data, sensors_pos, cmap='viridis', show=False) 
plt.title('b')
fig.colorbar(ax)
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

I added a "for" loop. :)

```
#Code to create fake data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,5), columns=list('abcde'),
index=list('nopqrstuvw'))
df.columns.name = 'level_0'
df.index.name = 'level_1'

#I load an array of shape (10, 2)
sensors_pos = sio.loadmat('/home/Coord_Slp_2D.mat')['Cor']


# I extract each column. From "a" to "e"
df1=df['Total Acc'].round(4)*100
df2=df1.reset_index().pivot('level_1', 'level_0', 'Total Acc')


for column in df2:
    data=df2[column].values
    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (8,5))
    ax,_ = plot_topomap(data, sensors_pos, cmap='viridis', show=False) 
    fig.colorbar(ax)
    fig.show()
```